# check_mk_agent output

Tags: java, jna, check-mk

I have a problem with `check_mk`.

I wrote a Java jar which is able to scan all active windows on my PC (more than 100 will be detected).

When I start `check_mk_agent.exe test` in `cmd` the jar file works like I expect.

In this case it detects all active windows im looking for and the output looks like:

```
<<<Test>>>
2 ErrorTitel:1_AACC
2 ErrorTitel:2_BB
2 ErrorTitel:3_Application_Error
```

These windows are selfmade just for testing it also works with all other visible windows on desktop if I want to look for them.

The big problem now is if I start `putty.exe` and enter the command 
`cmk -d hostname` the "jar file" seems not to detect any active windows so the output is:

```
<<<Test>>>
0 There_are_no_detected_windows
```

but the searched windows are still open so it should detect them.

Btw. the jar file can't detect any active window via the `putty.exe` `cmk -d hostname` command, thats not understandable for me.

All in all the problem is that the agent works well when I start it at the local machine manually but it doesn't when it will be started remotely by the monitoring server

Is there anyone who has a clue whats wrong. And if you need more detail I will pass all I can to figure this out.

I'm able now to scan for a specific WindowTitel with a batch file but the same problem appeared if I start it remotely. Is it possible that my files scan the wrong Scope and if so how can I determine the Scope or change it.

Comment: How are you entering the command in your Java jar?

Comment: I'm using JNA to scan the active windows and the jar itself will be started via a batch file.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but maybe the listening Check_MK_Agent is under a different user, and so not returning your user's windows?